# Sliding bathroom barn door covering cadet heater

Tags: bathroom, doors, heating, interior

This was a design decision I made a month ago and now after things putting together, I have a "duh" moment.

This is my bathroom door which will have a barn door sliding to the left:

[image]

Note that there is a cadet heater which has the cover 1" thick.

The barn door assembly will cover it if the bathroom door opens. I am able to make the sliding assembly to "stick out" 1" to prevent the door hitting the cadet cover.

However, **is this configuration OK?** Meaning, in order to get heat, the bathroom door has to be closed. If opened, the door will be 1/2" in front of the cadet heater. **Is that bad?**

Alternatively I can move the cadet heater to the left a bit and have a junction box where it is now. **What do you think?**

Comment: Can you put a louver in your door?

Comment: @renesis Sure but that is also work because it is hollow core door and it is nice as-is.

Comment: well, it is a solution, maybe not The solution.

Comment: @renesis Right, I am open to other creative ideas. As moving the cadet will need my electrician coming back! Urgh...

Comment: Can the door be installed on the other side of the wall?

Comment: Cut a square opening in the door lined up the the heater and put register covers on both sides of the door.

Comment: Cheapest and fastest solution may be to install an automatic closer on the Barn Door

Answer (score 1):

Do **not** cover that heater and a 1/2” gap is not sufficient either.

You will have to move it or re-design your door.

Comment: I am likely moving the cadet. I want to avoid junction box. The wiring might be too short to move it 2-3 feet to the left. BUT if I move the cadet higher and to the left, I may have enough wiring. Since the wires are coming top down (I know for fact). So is there a max height requirement for cadet location?

Comment: Check your instruction manual and make sure of any local regulations.

Comment: I have another thought. I am wondering if I should move the barn door inside the bathroom instead. I don't know if it looks odd. It would fit though.

Answer (score 0):

You do want to move the heater, you can raise the height that won’t be a problem as far as height 6’7” is the maximum height for a disconnecting means so I think you will be fine.  It looks like that cadet has the thermostat on the unit but the door being directly in front of it over time would cook the paint or finish and damage the door a little each time if in front.  so moving the heater is the best path forward.  As far as the junction box if needed you can make a fancy panel to cover the j box. Some on this site say no but the definition of accessible in the code allows panels made for removal without affecting the building finish is allowed. I do this all the time and make them look like picture frames.